# Analysis Services Parent Child Hierarchies

Tags: c#, sql, ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am having a strange issue with my child parent hierarchy where the calculation of the parent is incorrect when all the child unary operators is +.

Here is a run down of the parent child structure with unary operator.

```
-PBIT (+)
   -OtherIncome    (+)
   -GrossProfit    (+)
      -Sales       (+)
      -Cost Of Sales   (-)
```

This is the guide I followed http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/articles/57811.aspx and it all works great, except for the fact that any parent that has children all with the plus operator will add too much.

Here is output with data.

[image]

As you can see the PBIT value is adding Sales, Cost of Sales and Other Income together to get the value. (even when Cost of Sales unary operator is minus !!)

At first I thought it might just be excel, but looking at it and MDX query gives the same value.

Why? It only seems to be when the unary operator is +, any other ones work fine.

Comment: The only way I have been able to get it to calculate correctly is to add a dummy child in with a non plus unary operator. With no value it is not displayed in nonempty query but this is still quite horrible.

Comment: Do you have anything in your calculation script or your query that could interfere with these values? Maybe just remove everything except the `CALCULATE`, and then run a simple MDX query without any `WITH` clause. Does the wrong behavior persist?

Answer (score 1):

The post that you refer to does not describe setup of parent child hierarchies with unary operators, as I would have assumed from the context, but describes how one can use one member in several positions in a parent-child hierarchy. And this involves a many-to-mny relationship. According to http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/243429/wrong-calculation-for-unary-operator-with-many-to-many-relationships, it is a known limitation of Analysis Services that unary operator aggregation does not work properly with many-to-many-relationships, and it does not seem like Microsoft is going to change that anytime soon.

But at least it seems you have found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading chapter "Hierarchy Reclassification with Unary Operator" in many to many revolution white paper from http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/many2many/
It provides a nice solution for the problem.

Alternatively by using custom rollup members, you can achieve something similar.